# Sequelize associations / models suddenly not recognized when nothing was changed, Vague Error Cannot Read Property 'field' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, sequelize.js

I've been working on this project using React, node, sequelize, Redux for a while and everything has been running great. The other day I decided to update some of my node packages as I try to do every so often, but Sequelize suddenly broke right after I ran `npm update --save/--save-dev`.

All of a sudden, when I try to run the app, my initial fetches to sql fail, and my sequelize models are throwing an error:

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:130
    this.sourceKeyField = this.source.rawAttributes[this.sourceKey].field || this.sourceKey;
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at new BelongsToMany (/Users/dlmusic/Desktop/Cullan - Site/Metadata-Tagging-With-Redux/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:130:69)
    at Function.belongsToMany (/Users/dlmusic/Desktop/Cullan - Site/Metadata-Tagging-With-Redux/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:64:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dlmusic/Desktop/Cullan - Site/Metadata-Tagging-With-Redux/authenticationBI.js:63:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dlmusic/Desktop/Cullan - Site/Metadata-Tagging-With-Redux/api/routes/backgroundInstrumentalsRoutes.js:6:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dlmusic/Desktop/Cullan - Site/Metadata-Tagging-With-Redux/server.js:4:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
```

That's weird. I've only been working on the front-end recently. I haven't even touched any of the sequelize models, associations, or controllers in over a month, not to mention the associations have been working without error for over three months, yet all of a sudden it's saying its not valid.

Okay. Fine. Not a big deal. Sequelize just didn't like one of those modules, so I'll reset my git head, trash my modules folder, and figure out which module it doesn't like.

I reset git head, delete my modules folder, and run `npm i`.

THE SAME ERROR IS STILL COMING UP WHEN I WAS NEVER GETTING THIS ERROR BEFORE.

This is preventing the sequelize association tables from being created, thus my app can't even start.

I comment out the sequelize associations causing the error and now the sequelize is running fine, but I need those associations in order for certain features of my application to work.

I'm about ready to pull my hair out this shit is frustrating the hell out of me. I don't even know what to do anymore. I tried messing with my associations by changing the methods but literally nothing works.

Here are the sequelize associations it apparently has an issue with. To clarify, there can be multiple styles per category, but each style only has one category.

```
CategoryBI.belongsToMany(StyleBI,
  { constraints: false,
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: "cat_id",
    sourceKey: "style_id",
    through: "cat_styles"
  });

StyleBI.belongsTo(CategoryBI,
  { constraints: false,
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: "cat_id",
    targetKey: "cat_id",
    through: "cat_styles"
  });
```

AND the models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define("categories", {
    cat_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    cat_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: "categories",
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define("styles", {
    style_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    cat_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(8),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: "0"
    },
    style_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    style_img: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(55),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: "styles",
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I change the association syntax and it started working again. I am completely baffled as to how the association would have all of a sudden stopped working but here is what I changed it to.

```
CategoryBI.hasMany(StyleBI,
  { constraints: false,
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: "style_id",
    sourceKey: "cat_id"
  });

StyleBI.belongsTo(CategoryBI,
  { constraints: false,
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: "style_id",
    targetKey: "cat_id"
  });
```

I removed the through table and flipped the association keys.